# Objective C - JSON data unavailable after being returned correctly

Tags: objective-c, json

I'm trying to put in a tableview the result of a JSON that is returned correctly.
The problem is that I can only access the data within the block where the information is returned, even assigning the result to a instance variable.
My code is as follows:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.my_url.com.br/app/?type=list&info=15,16&lat=some_data&long=some_data"];

ASIHTTPRequest *_request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = _request;

request.requestMethod = @"POST";
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseString);
    NSDictionary *root = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:request.responseData options:0 error:nil];
    self.data = [root objectForKey:@"listing"];

    NSLog(@"Data returned: %@", data);  //Everything works well. The data returned is printed correctly

}];
[request setFailedBlock:^{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];

[request startAsynchronous];

NSLog(@"Data only: %@", data);  //At this point, the "data" content is nil
```

This is my "ListDataController.h" file definitions :

```
@interface ListDataController : UITableViewController{
ApplicationCell *tmpCell;
    NSArray *data;
    UILabel *status ;       
UINib *cellNib;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ApplicationCell *tmpCell;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *data;
```

The JSON returned :
    Data self: (
        {
        Icon = "Baseball.png";
        Name = Baseball;
        NumRatings = 106;
        Price = "$2.98";
        Publisher = "Super Sportz, Inc.";
        Rating = "3.5";
    },
        {
        Icon = "Checkers.png";
        Name = Checkers;
        NumRatings = 87;
        Price = Free;
        Publisher = "Gameitoids, Inc.";
        Rating = 4;
    }
)

The question is : why I can not access the instance variable "data" outside the block, even assigning it the result of json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access `data` outside the block, but it is set to `nil`. You are probably setting `data` properly, just not at the moment you thought.

By the time you execute the final log, the completion block has not run yet. The request is **asynchronous**, meaning the completion block will execute at some point in the future. This is a key concept to understand when working with blocks.

**UPDATE**:

To procress the data once it has been retreived, you can call the desired from the completion block:

```
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseString);
    NSDictionary *root = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:request.responseData options:0 error:nil];
    self.data = [root objectForKey:@"listing"];

NSLog(@"Data returned: %@", data);  //Everything works well. The data returned is printed correctly

    [self handleData:self.data];  // you would have to define this method your self

}];
```

One thing to consider, if you are updating the UI based on `self.data`, you would want to make sure you execute `handleData` on the main thread.

Some Links:

- [Objective C Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html)
- [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091)

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is your log

```
NSLog(@"Data only: %@", data);  //At this point, the "data" content is nil
```

will be executed well before getting the data.You are using asynchronous request using block that is the execution will happen on a seperate thread without affecting the main thread execution

and on completion of the seperate thread the completion block get executed .Hence response only loads into data at this point only

For better understandability

- Put breakpoints in both log and completion block

You can see the execution on the log happens before the completion block

EDIT :
you can do the operations in the completion block after response assigned to the `data`

```
   [request setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

        NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseString);
        NSDictionary *root = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:request.responseData options:0 error:nil];
        self.data = [root objectForKey:@"listing"];

        NSLog(@"Data returned: %@", data);  //Everything works well. The data returned is printed correctly


        //DO here WHATEVER you want to do after getting response
    //eg:
        [table reloadData]


    }];
```

The request when get all the data will execute the completion block.So whatever you want to do after getting the response can be done in the completion block

Comment: I had already noticed this by analyzing the log and the milliseconds of operations, but did not understand why happened. Thanks for clarifying. 
But how do I get around this? I need the application wait for the return of JSON, then assign it to the variable that will be used by the tableview.

Comment: yeah u can do it in the completion block

Comment: You can get around this by requesting the data synchonously. You would not want to do that because then your app will freeze at that very point until the data is finally received. That might take ages under certain conditions (up to ip timeout).

Comment: @AlanoTeles You can add the [table reloadData] in completion block

Comment: Changing the request to synchronous solved the problem. The amount of information to be returned is very small, at most 10 entries. But in the case of using an asynchronous request, how to proceed?

Comment: @AlanoTeles : Edited the answer.Last line

Answer (score 0):

1. timing (like the 2 answers above)
2. to write into variables living outside the block you have to use the __block directive before the variable declaration. I am not sure if instance variables are special to this, but to be sure you could use some  temp variable for storing the result before assign it finally to the ivar.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"Data returned: %@", data);  //Everything works well. The data returned is printed correctly
```

Fine. What is your problem? This is the completion block. It is executed when all data was received. Any access to data before that point in time will end up in nil in its best case or outated/wron/unpredictable data in its worst case.